# How can I possibly speed up a Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I have installed a desktop computer with the technical preview of Windows 10.  It is running deadly slow that I have to remove it.  But before I am able to do so, I think I need to have it responding to me in a reasonable amount of time first.  I don't know if there is anything to improve the physical ability, as my computer has got 8GB RAM already.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a Technical Preview, it is almost by definition buggy. Of course you can try standard approach to speeding up a computer by adding more RAM, replacing HDD with SSD. But i would not expect much at this stage. Having said this, my installation of TP in VMWare runs fairly fast and smooth. And i DO like the new "Start" menu.

Comment: The Win10 preview should not be any slower than WIn8/Win8.1 on the same hardware. There's the possibility that you have a buggy driver (most likely with a technical preview) causing issues.

Comment: How can I check which part is it likely to be causing the problem?  I was wondering if it was because there are too many disk access.

Comment: Secret revealed.  After leaving the computer alone for a whole night and a morning, I returned from lunch and managed to restart the computer.  It was because the computer was downloading updates that it installed after I restarted.  Get finger crossed.

Comment: Everything looks fine now.  It was an update called KB3001512.  See this:

https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3001512

Comment: And later it turns out that heaps and heaps of updating are loading the days after I have the installation.  It takes at least a week, I think, for the system to become stable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough RAM, go and get a SSD. Nothing else will improve the computers speed more. (regardless of the computers OS)

Comment: There's any number of possible non-I/O issues causing slowdowns. Without identifying the bottleneck first, this is answer is purely guessing, and poorly at that.

Comment: You are right in that manner - but that was an answer to "`I don't know if there is anything to improve the physical ability, as my computer has got 8GB RAM already.`".